# How to doublespace a document

Tags: margins, fontsize, line-spacing

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX, using Overleaf as the site to compile the document. I want to make doublespace between lines.

Can I know: How to set double-spaced text (1-inch margins, 12-point font) in Overleaf? Currently, my text style is:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{PrintVersion}}{
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=1.25in]{geometry}   % For twoside document
}{
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=1.25in]{geometry}   % For oneside document
}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext} % Lots of math symbols and environments
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including graphics 

\usepackage{nomentbl} 
\makenomenclature 

\usepackage{ifpdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you familiar with the `setspace` package?

Comment: @setspace many thanks for replying, no, I did not.

Comment: depending on the documentclass you use, setspace options may already be included. In memoir, for example, you can just declare `\DoubleSpacing*` in the preamble